# What means lne "The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17d0) has exited with code 2:"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, dialog

After i closed my compiled multithread dialog based app in MFC, i saw line:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17d0) has exited with code 2
```

Instead of:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17d0) has exited with code 0
```

But all closed correctly. What does it mean?

Edit:
Here is thread func:

```
UINT CrMainDlg::WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID Param)
{
    if(Param == NULL)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Params in thread func are equal to NULL!");
        return 0;
    }

    inputParam* p = (inputParam*)Param;
    int startIndex = p->index;
    int index = p->curIndex;
    int direction = 1;

    for (int i = 0; (static_cast<unsigned>(startIndex + i) >= 0) && (static_cast<unsigned>(startIndex + i) < ThumbnailList.size()); i += direction)
    {
        if (flagToThreadFinished)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (ThumbnailList.size() == 0)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"Here it is!!");
        }

        EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

        if (ThumbnailList[startIndex + i].second->IsLoaded)
        {
            i += direction;
            continue;
        }

        CString path = ThumbnailList[startIndex + i].first;

        try
        {
            ThumbnailList[startIndex + i].second->LoadThumbNail(path);
            WPARAM a = MAKEWPARAM(startIndex + i, 0);
            ::PostMessage(p->m_hWnd, THUMBNAIL_WAS_LOADED, a, 0);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"Something bad was happend while loading!");
        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);


        if (startIndex != p->index)
        {
            startIndex = p->index;
            i = -1;
            direction = 1;
            continue;
        }


        if (startIndex + i == ThumbnailList.size() - 1)
        {
            i = -1; 
            direction = -1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

And here is ON_CLOSE dialog handler:

```
void CrMainDlg::OnClose()
{
    flagToThreadFinished = true;
    DWORD check = WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
    DWORD checkError = GetLastError();


    for (std::vector <std::pair<CString, CommonThumbnail*>>::iterator someIter = ThumbnailList.begin(); someIter != ThumbnailList.end(); someIter++)
    {
        if (someIter->second != nullptr)
        {
            delete someIter->second;
        }
    }

    ThumbnailList.clear();
    flagToThreadFinished = false;
    CDialogEx::OnClose();
```

}

Value of GetLastError is 3435973836;

Comment: How dou you exit your thread ? With the ExitThread function ?

Comment: WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE); - but it returns FFFFFFF, mean faild... i do this on the ON_CLOSE handler.

Comment: WaitForSigleObject does not terminate the thread. It just waits for a single object to get signalled. What does GetLastError() return after the failed call to WaitForSignelObject ? Edit your question and show some more relevant code.

Comment: Edited; Value of GetLastError is 3435973836 mean "CCCCCCCC"

Comment: What is the variable _thread_ in line 4 of the CrmainDlg::OnClose function ? If it's not the thread handle, then WaitForSingleObject wont work of course. What's the content of checkError *after* GelLastError has been called ? It's hard to believe that it is 0xcccccccc.

Comment: One more thing: the expression *static_cast<unsigned>(startIndex + i)* will never be smaller than zero because you casted *startIndex + i* to unsigned, and therefore the expression *static_cast<unsigned>(startIndex + i) >= 0)* will always be TRUE.